# How to use "prefetch related" to get many to many field in DRF serialzers?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In the below code, I need `badge_color` and `badge_text` should be shown under the `user_detail` method

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user_badges = models.ManyToManyField(Badges,related_name='badges', null=True,blank=True,)

class Badges(models.Model):
    badge_text  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    badge_color = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=50, unique=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField("date of comment", default=timezone.now)
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=2500)
```

Serializer for comments Class

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields =[date,comment_text,user_detail]
    
    def get_user_detail(self, obj):
        if obj.user:
           return {
                "id": obj.user.id,
                "user_name": obj.user.user_name,
                "profile_pic": profile_pic,
            }
        else:
            return None
```

Views.py

```
..........
.............
qs=Comments.objects.all()
comments=CommentsSerializer(qs, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
class BadgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Badges
        fields =[badge_color, badge_text]

class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields =[date,comment_text,user_detail]
    
    def get_user_detail(self, obj):
        if obj.user:
           badges = BadgeSerializer(source='obj.user.user_badges', many=True)
           return {
                "id": obj.user.id,
                "user_name": obj.user.user_name,
                "profile_pic": profile_pic,
                "user_badges": badges.data
                
            }
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: sorry, I missed that you are doing this at `comment`. I have updated my answer, changed the source, check it.

Comment: There is no model required in BadgeSerializer??

Comment: still getting null values  no luck :((

Comment: are you sure that there is data? if there is none so null is correct, so make sure there is some data there

Comment: if there is data then try `source='obj.user.user_user_badges_relation_set'` at `BadgeSerializer` and let me know if this works to update the answer

Comment: sorry still  no results